# jQuery to JavaScript (insert row after other one)

Tags: javascript

**Problem:** I have a small function that moves a row to the next one and back inside a table, it's in jQuery and I need it in JavaScript. Since I pretty much always work with jQuery and don't have the time to figure it out I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me do it.

**I tried something like this but again I don't have the time and need it fast:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('up').length; i++) {
     document.getElementsByClassName('up')[i].addEventListener('click',
     function() {
        let trFirst = document.getElementsByTag('tr:first');
        let row = document.this.parentNode;
     });
}
```

**Solution would be this in JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".up,.down").click(function () {
      var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
      if ($(this).is(".up")) {
         row.insertBefore(row.prev());
      } else {
         row.insertAfter(row.next());
      }
   });
});
```

I understand that I need to learn this and can't use code I fully understand but like I said I need it quick and I know for some of you guys it's just a couple minutes work. **Thanks a lot for taking the time!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function parentTr(element) {
  let parent = element.parentNode;
  while(parent != null) {
    if(parent.nodeName === "TR") {
      return parent;
    }
    parent = parent.parentNode;
  }
}

let table = document.getElementById('table');

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('up')).forEach(upButton => {
  upButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let currentTr = parentTr(upButton);
    let previousTr = currentTr.previousElementSibling;
    if(previousTr) {
      previousTr.parentNode.insertBefore(currentTr, previousTr);
    }
  });
});

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('down')).forEach(downButton => {
  downButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let currentTr = parentTr(downButton);
    let nextTr = currentTr.nextElementSibling;
    if(nextTr) {
      currentTr.parentNode.insertBefore(nextTr, currentTr);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table border="1" id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>row 1</td>
    <td>
      <button class="up">Up</button>
      <button class="down">Down</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2</td>
    <td>
      <button class="up">Up</button>
      <button class="down">Down</button>
    </td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 3</td>
    <td>
      <button class="up">Up</button>
      <button class="down">Down</button>
    </td>   
  </tr>
</table>
```